# In Oracle PLSQL ,Not able to update the VARCHAR2 column with alphanumeri if the column already has the numeric value in it issue

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, check-constraints

For the very first time VARCHAR2 column has been stored with numeric value i.e 123123 ..and if i try to update the same VARCHAR2 column with the Alphanumeric values the its not updating it and giving "Invalid number" error ...is Oracle casting implicitly to numeric based on the previous value stored though the column datatype is VARCHAR2..
Below is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "CUST_DETAIL" 
(   "ACCOUNT_NO" NUMBER, 
    "EXTERNAL_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "DESCRIPTION_TEST" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CUST_ACCT_PK" ON "CUST_DETAIL" ("ACCOUNT_NO") 

ALTER TABLE "CUST_DETAIL" 
   ADD CONSTRAINT "CUST_CHECK_DES" 
   CHECK (DESCRIPTION_TEST IS NULL OR (DESCRIPTION_TEST is not null AND DESCRIPTION_TEST >6)) ENABLE;

  ALTER TABLE "CUST_DETAIL" 
    ADD CONSTRAINT "CUST_ACCT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ACCOUNT_NO")
```

```
INSERT INTO CUST_DETAIL VALUES(9012344,'SL345A','123134123')
update CUST_DETAIL set DESCRIPTION_TEST='U_CODNAD_0o1'
```

```
ERROR==> .Error starting at line : 13 in command -
update CUST_DETAIL set DESCRIPTION_TEST='U_CODNAD_0o1'
Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: No, it won't be doing that unless you tell it to. Please edit your question to show the table DDL, including any constraints and triggers, and sample data, the actual statement you are running and the full error stack you get back.

Comment: Thank you for the reply..i have updated the details in the question.

Comment: Yes Alex Poole, after disabling the constraint i am able to update the alphanumeric..so DESCRIPTION_TEST IS NULL OR (DESCRIPTION_TEST is not null AND DESCRIPTION_TEST >6 is making that issue..but why when we compare the length its giving that casting invalid number issue..thanks in advance.

Comment: `DESCRIPTION_TEST >6` makes no sense. You are trying to compare a varchar column with a number. What do you expect that condition to do?

Comment: yes right..my mistake..my requirement is to compare the length of the VARCHAR...instead of finding the length i have mistakenly comparing the value of the columns :( thank you for the response ..